# How to split a list of strings to smaller chunks of lists of strings

Tags: c#, string, list, linq, loops

The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

I have a `List<string>`, let's call it "`initialList`".

I need to interact with all the strings in that list, so I have to enumerate it. However, the problem comes that I have to take "x" elements of it every time I interact.

`x` is a `new Random().Next(_minValue, _maxValue);` so that will be random every time.

Here is a real example of what I want to do:

Suppose the list `initialList` contains the following elements:
`test, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6, test7, test8, test9, test10, test11, test12`.

I want to loop through all elements and take 2-3 strings at a time and save a new string with combined ones.

So, one possible output (varies depending which values will the Random return) is:

```
{ "test",  "test1", "test2" }, 
{ "test3", "test4" }, 
{ "test5", "test6" }, 
{ "test7", "test8" }, 
{ "test9", "test10", "test11" }, 
{ "test12" }
```

What I thought of doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _users.Count; i += _random.Next(_minMentions, _maxMentions + 1))
{
    var mergedString = ?? // get the values of the next _random.Next(_minMentions, _maxMentions + 1) strings
}
```

I was thinking, but if I generate the random number outside the loop, then it will always be the same. I want the amount of strings to be random each time.

Also, thought of doing LINQ by selecting the elements with index, but don't know how to proceed from there.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And what happens if after all your random takings you're left with a single element at the end? That won't fit into your 2-3 elements per group requirement.

Comment: @itsme86 In the example he provided, the last element (which is alone) is ... alone.

Comment: "I want to loop through all elements and take 2-3 strings at a time and save a new string with combined ones" - as I understand, a result should be just a list of strings?

Comment: @VadzimDvorak it's not a big deal, as I will adjust it later on for my needs. but I like your solution, it's somewhat similar to other answer but unique. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is to use LINQ `Skip` to skip over the elements you have already processed and `Take` to extract the random number of elements.

```
const int _minValue = 2;
const int _maxValue = 4; // note max of random is exclusive, so this config takes 2 or 3 elements

var _random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

List<string> initialList = new List<string>{"test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test10", "test11", "test12"};

var currentPosition = 0;

while (currentPosition < initialList.Count()) {
    var toTake = _random.Next(_minValue, _maxValue);
    var mergedString = string.Join(", ", initialList.Skip(currentPosition).Take(toTake)); 
    currentPosition += toTake;
}
```

Note that this code might result in the last `mergedString` only containing one element (the last one).

Working example: [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ywgy5g).

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will give you an idea.

```
var mergedList = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < initialList.Count; ){
    var n = _random.Next(2,4);
    mergedList.Add(initialList.Skip(i).Take(n).Aggregate((x,y) => x + y));
    i += n;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try direct `GroupBy`:

```
  List<string> initialList = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 15)
    .Select(i => $"test{i}")
    .ToList();

  int _minMentions = 2;
  int _maxMentions = 3;

  // Random(1): to make outcome reproducible
  // In real life should be new Random();  
  Random _random = new Random(1); 

  int group = 0;
  int groupLength = 0;

  var result = initialList
    .Select((item) => {
      if (--groupLength <= 0) {
        group += 1;
        groupLength = _random.Next(_minMentions, _maxMentions + 1);
      }

      return new { item, group };
    })
    .GroupBy(item => item.group)
    .Select(chunk => chunk
       .Select(item => item.item)
       .ToList())
    .ToList();

  string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(items => string.Join(", ", items))); 

  Console.Write(test);
```

Outcome:

```
test1, test2
test3, test4
test5, test6
test7, test8, test9
test10, test11, test12
test13, test14
test15
```

Comment: @Filip Cordas: it's technically possible (we can put `group` and `groupLength` into anonymous class: `var result = initialList.Select(item => new {item, group = 0, groupSize = _random.Next(_minMentions, _maxMentions + 1)})...`) but I doubt if it's worth implementing (overcoming side effect on two specially implemented local variables)

Comment: That is true, but if it had no side effects you would not have to use ToList at the end and could work with only enumerable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IEnumerable.Skip and Take to loop over your initial list and create blocks of the desidered size until you have elements to process.

```
List<string> initiallist = new List<string>
{"test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test10", "test11", "test12"};

// We store the results here    
List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();

Random rnd = new Random();
int pos = 0;
while (pos < initiallist.Count())
{
    // Define a block size of 2/3 elements
    int block = rnd.Next(2,4);

    // Extract the block size from the previous position
    List<string> temp = initiallist.Skip(pos).Take(block).ToList();

    // Add the sublist to our results
    result.Add(temp);

    // Point to the beginning of the next block
    pos += block;

}
```

Comment: I was trying to do something similar with nested `for` loops. Was getting somewhat close to your solution. However, a question, shouldn't there be check if `pos + block` exceeds the count of the list?

Comment: _Take_ will ignore the _block_ value if you have requested to much elements and returns only the elements available from the starting point given by _pos_

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve it using Linq:

```
var initialList = new[]
{
    "test", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test10", "test11",
    "test12"
};

var newLists = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
var rnd = new Random();
int minMentions = 2;
int maxMentions = 3;
int c = 0;

while (c < initialList.Length)
{
    int elementsToTake = rnd.Next(minMentions, maxMentions + 1);
    newLists.Add(initialList.Skip(c).Take(elementsToTake));
    c += elementsToTake;
}
```

Which results in (randomly):

```
{ test, test2, test3 }
{ test4, test5 }
{ test6, test7, test8 }
{ test9, test10, test11 }
{ test12 }
```

Note that `Take` will only take available items, so you don't need to worry about the `elementsToTake` being bigger than what `initialList` has left.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are plenty of good answers but here is something if you like IEnumerable

```
public static class EnumerableGroupOf
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> RandomGroupOf<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int[] groupLengths)
        {
            Random random = new Random();

            var itemsLeft = source;

            while (itemsLeft.Any())
            {
                var count = groupLengths[random.Next(0, groupLengths.Length)];

                var items = itemsLeft.Take(count);

                itemsLeft = itemsLeft.Skip(count);

                yield return items;
            }
        }
    }
```

This wont be doing skip and take on all the items just the reaming ones so might perform a bit better with Enumerable.